# Colored Tabs missing in VS2022 17.3 (not preview)

Tags: visual-studio-2022

[Here](https://davecallan.com/explicitly-set-tab-colour-per-project-when-using-coloured-tabs-in-visual-studio-2022/) it is stated that...

```
Coloured tabs is supported in Visual Studio 2022. From release 17.1 Preview 2 we can now explicitly set the colour per project…
```

I should look like this:

[image]

I am using VS2022 Version 17.2.3, and I don't see this.
I see this instead:

[image]

I wonder what is happening here.

Is Version 17.2.3 perhaps older than the said 17.1 Preview 2?
Is it possible that 17.1 Preview 2 is used for active development and therefore newer than official newer versions? I just don't understand it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
It's there, but it needs to be activated first:

[image]

And here it is German... I just couldn't find it in German language, so I had to switch language to English first in order to find it LOL.

Here it is in German:
[image]